# Know when the "Datacontext" is changed in the code behind of a UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml, user-controls

I'm creating a usercontrol for lightswitch. This is basically a Silverlight usercontrol, which receive the businessObject on the "DataContext" property.

I can bind in the xaml side items without a problem, but on the code behind, I don't know how to get informed when the dataContext has changed?

I need that for one special binding.

Thank you very much!

Comment: In SL 4 it's a kinda stuck. One of the options is to make your BO reposible for handling that change - what would you do inside DataContext_changed should it be available?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can extend the control class (`UserControl` in your case) and add a new `DependencyProperty` wrapping `DataContext` in order to expose `PropertyChanged`. See [these](http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2008/12/29/how-to-know-when-the-datacontext-changed-in-your-control.aspx) [three](http://forums.silverlight.net/t/13421.aspx/2/10) [posts](http://www.lhotka.net/weblog/AddingDataContextChangedInSilverlight.aspx) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936563/detecting-datacontext-changed-in-silverlight). Alternatively, it may be the case that you don't really need to listen to `DataContextChanged`, depending on what you're trying to do, since it might be more appropriate to handle the changes in your model.

Finally, if you have the patience and option, I hear that SL 5 exposes `DataContextChanged`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't wait on SL5 :(. I've checked your link and the first one seems to be the more interessant. But in lightswitch, I don't have the choice, the item is bound on "DataContext", not "MyDataContext" or anything else. So, can I redefine the DataContext item which my own Dependency property?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with LightSwitch. You could try extending the control and adding `public new Object DataContext` in order to hide the original `DataContext` on the LS control. Then you can create a `MyDataContext` property and set that whenever `DataContext` gets set, in order to fire the event. This would be a problem, though, if the LS controls do any tricks inside the get or set of `DataContext`, since those would be lost.

Comment: I finally used this: it works great: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38559/Silverlight-DataContext-Changed-Event.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid you cannot set the static readonly field again unless you do it with a "new".

You might be able to catch the DataContext changed via a data binding to the DataContext dependencyproperty. 
e.g. Register a new dp named "MyDataContext", and create a Binding.
DataContext is the binding source and MyDataContext is the binding target, that is DataContext ---> MyDataContext.  So everytime the DataContext you gonna get your MyDataContext  dp changed callback.  I think this gonna work but not tested.

the code is like:

```
// dp declaration..
public static readonly DependencyProperty MyDataContextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(null, "MyDataContext", typeof(object), typeof(MyControl), new PropertyMetadata(MyDataContextChangedCallback));


// create binding in constructor or initialization.
Binding binding = new Binding("DataContext");
BindingOperations.SetBinding(this, MyDataContextProperty, binding);
```

Thanks